# React combobox select with an image and discription

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am looking for a combo box so that each line will have a title, description and an image. I need that when the combo box is closed I will see the title of the picked line and the image.

Is there is some king of a library that doing such a thing?

My project is written in React and TypeScript.

I am looking for something like this:

[image: The image is of a dropdown and every item has an image to the left and icon on the right]

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is called a dropdown.

Comment: Check out [react-select](https://react-select.com/home). It might do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution. I used the DropDown component of 'semantic-ui-react'
my code looks like this:

```
export default class CPComboBoxWithIcon extends Dropdown {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    let pickedComboBox  = this.props.comboBoxContent.find((x: { isPicked?: any; })=>x.isPicked === true)
    this.setPickedComboBox(pickedComboBox.image.src , pickedComboBox.text)

    this.state = {
        sel_img: this.getPickedComboBox()
    };
}

pickedComboBox : any;

setPickedComboBox = (imgSrc:any , comboBoxText:string )=> {
    this.pickedComboBox  = (
        <span>
            <Image avatar src={imgSrc} size={"tiny"}/>  {comboBoxText}
         </span>
    )
}
getPickedComboBox =  ()=> {
    return this.pickedComboBox;
}

exposedCampaignOnChange = (e: any, {value}: any) => {
     let chosenComboBox  = this.props.comboBoxContent.find((x: { value: any; })=>x.value == value)
    this.setPickedComboBox(chosenComboBox.image.src, chosenComboBox.text);
    this.setState({
        sel_img: this.getPickedComboBox(),
    });
};


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Dropdown
                trigger={this.state.sel_img}
                fluid
                selection
                options={this.props.comboBoxContent}
                onChange={this.exposedCampaignOnChange}>
            </Dropdown>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}